# Samsung GT B5330 won't turn on

Tags: power-on

My Samsung GT B5330 doesn't want to power on. I charge it and when I try to turn it on it just vibrates (short vibration) and doesn't start. I let it charge for 2 hours and then it still did not start. What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue. Possibly a bad battery, possibly a bad connection between the charger and the battery. Can you replace the battery and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take it to a repair shop, as it sounds like a hardware issue.

Most likely something has happened to the hardware, and the device will no longer power on.

You may also want to try removing the battery for a while, and then reconnecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by pulling out the SIM card, starting the phone without it, then reinserting the SIM card after turning the phone off, of course.